# Combobox function that will change properties of a similar named textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox with two options as an output, one is "Completed" the other is "N/A". When one of these options is selected I want a text box to output a message and and change the font in the textbox. I have named the combobox SC1 and the the textbox ID1 as I will use the function to change multiple textboxes throughout my form.

I am currently using a function in the Afterupdate property of the Combobox (SC1) and refer to the function this way: =chkclick([SC1])

This should run the following function with sName referring to SC1 (Combobox) -

```
 Private Function chkClick(sName As String)
      Dim IDnumber As String
      Me.Controls(sName).SetFocus
        If Me.Controls(sName).Value = "Completed" Then
            IDnumber = Split(sName, "C") 
            Form.Controls("ID" & IDnumber).Value = ("Completed by " & (Environ$("Username")))
            Form.Controls("ID" & IDnumber).ForeColor = 10
            Form.Controls("ID" & IDnumber).Controls(0).Visible = True

        ElseIf Me.Controls(sName).Value = "Not Applicable" Then
            Form.Controls("ID" & IDnumber).Value = ("Not completed, please leave comments when saving")
            Form.Controls("ID" & IDnumber).ForeColor = 10
            Form.Controls("ID" & IDnumber).Controls(0).Visible = True
        End If
    End Function
```

But instead I get the following error message - "The expression After Update you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Microsoft Access Can't find the field 'Completed' referred to in your expression.'

I've tried lots of different ways of writing it but I'm at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the line:

```
IDnumber = Split(sName, "C")
```

For example, when I run this code in Access:

```
Dim s As String
s = Split("abc", "b")   ' can't assign array to plain string
```

I get `Error 13: Type Mismatch`. This is because you can't assign an array to a simple string variable.

The fix? Dimension your string as an array:

```
Dim s() As String
s = Split("abc", "b")
Debug.Print s(0)        ' works
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to address the issue (this may be a problem I have to deal with later so thanks anyway). When I try to run it again the message 'Microsoft Access Can't find the field 'Completed' referred to in your expression.' and it highlights this line - If Me.Controls(sName).Value = "Completed" Then. It looks like it cannot read the 'Completed' selection in the combobox but I am not sure how to change it

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. When I referred to the function as =chkclick([SC1]) in the properties window it was giving me the output "completed" instead of the name. I changed the function in the properties window to =chkclick("SC1") and this then referred to the control name and the rest of it I could work out with Kismerts answer